# Android - EditText positioning within a TableView row and colum

Tags: layout, android-edittext, tableview

If someone could point out the really obvious setting im missing I would be grateful!

Im working on a screen layout that has rows and 3 columns.  All I want to do is put a EditText control into the first row.  Below is the code. Unfortunately I dont have the reputation to post a screen shot - sorry.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="75dp">

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/textpin"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_span="2"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:cursorVisible="false"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:textColor="#3399ff"
            android:textSize="35sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnBack"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="130dp"
            android:background="#fffafafa"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_del"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
            android:textSize="40sp" />

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn1"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="130dp"
            android:background="#fffafafa"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_1"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="30sp" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn2"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="130dp"
            android:background="#fffafafa"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_2"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="30sp" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn3"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="130dp"
            android:background="#fffafafa"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_3"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="30sp" />

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn4"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="130dp"
            android:background="#fffafafa"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_4"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="30sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn5"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="130dp"
            android:background="#fffafafa"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_5"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="30sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn6"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="130dp"
            android:background="#fffafafa"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_6"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="30sp" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn7"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="130dp"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_7"
            android:background="#fffafafa"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="30sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn8"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="130dp"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_8"
            android:background="#fffafafa"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="30sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn9"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="130dp"
            android:background="#fffafafa"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_9"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="30sp" />

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn0"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="130dp"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_0"
            android:background="#fffafafa"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="30sp" />

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/cancelB"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="130dp"
            android:background="#fffafafa"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_cancel"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/confermB"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="130dp"
            android:background="#fffafafa"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_ok"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="25sp" />
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

Has anyone any ideas?

Thanks

Steve

Comment: Does anybody have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much messing around I found this fixed it :-

```
<EditText
            android:id="@+id/textpin"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_span="2"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:cursorVisible="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:textColor="#3399ff"
            android:textSize="40sp" />
```